# JqGrid cell edit using cell editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to edit two separate cells in jqgrid using cell edit?

currently i have this.

```
 {name: 'lecturer', index: 'lecturer', width: 13, sortable: false},
 {name: 'crn', index: 'crn', width: 7, editable: true, sortable: false},
 {name: 'grade', index: 'grade', width: 7, editable: true, sortable: false}
],
'cellEdit': true, 
'cellsubmit': 'remote',
 cellurl: '<c:url value="/finalgrades/create/"/>' + row_id
```

As you can see I have editable for crn and grade. however i need to pass two separate urls for each case. one for grade and one for crn.

as mentioned before is it possible to do this using cell edit?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to use [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) instead of [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing).